# Make numbers 93 using the digits 2, 0, 1, 8

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

I have a 1 to 100 building challenge with 2, 0, 1, 8, all made but 93 is not made.
I need your help!

This is similar to the "Four fours" puzzle, but using the digits 2, 0, 1 and 8.

Rules:

- Use all four digits exactly once
- Allowed operations: +, -, x, ÷, ! (factorial), exponentiation, square
  root Parentheses and grouping (e.g. "21") are also allowed
- Squaring uses the digit 2 so expressions using multiple twos, like
  2222 or 12+8212+82, are not allowed
- Multi-digit numbers and decimal points can be used such as 20, 102,
  .02 but you CANNOT make 30 by combining (2+1)0
- Recurring decimals can be used using the '

For example :

.2' = 0.222222.....

.12' = 0.1222222.....

.1'2' = 0.12121212.....

Comment: Does square root also consume the 2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is valid by your rules :

> $ .1^{-2} - 8 + 0! $
>  $= 100 - 8 + 1 $
>  $ = 93 $

Comment: _Very_ nice! How long did it take you to come up with it?

Comment: I can't really tell since I was working in parallel^^. I just figured 10^2 - 8 was 92 and asked myself if I could get rid of the 0 for later use

Comment: Oh, my god! This is crazy! I've been thinking about it for more than a week, but it didn't work out. But I can finally finish the 2018 Challenge! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I am so close with:
$\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{12!}}}+80 \approx 92.16 $

Comment: Not using factorials or roots, $10^2-8=92$

Comment: Oh, if only you could use the ceiling function!