# Use 2, 0, 1 and 8 to make 109

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Assemble a formula using the numbers $2$, $0$, $1$, and $8$ in any order that equals 109. You may use the operations $x + y$, $x - y$, $x \times y$, $x \div y$, $x!$, $\sqrt{x}$, $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}x]{y}$ and $x^y$, as long as all operands are either $2$, $0$, $1$, or $8$. Operands may of course also be derived from calculations e.g. $10+(\sqrt{8*2})!$. You may also use brackets to clarify order of operations, and you may concatenate two or more of the four digits you start with (such as $2$ and $8$ to make the number $28$) if you wish. You may only use each of the starting digits once and you must use all four of them. I'm afraid that concatenation of numbers from calculations is not permitted, but answers with concatenations which get $109$ will get plus one from me.

Double, triple, etc. factorials (n-druple-factorials), such as $4!! = 4 \times 2$ are not allowed, but factorials of factorials are fine, such as $(4!)! = 24!$. I will upvote answers with double, triple and n-druple-factorials which get 109, but will not mark them as correct.

Here are some examples to this problem:

- [Use 2 0 1 and 8 to make 67](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71748/use-2-0-1-and-8-to-make-67)
- [Make numbers 93 using the digits 2, 0, 1, 8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58743/make-numbers-93-using-the-digits-2-0-1-8)
- [Make numbers 1 - 30 using the digits 2, 0, 1, 8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58633/make-numbers-1-30-using-the-digits-2-0-1-8)

many thanks to the authors of these questions for inspiring this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83587/discussion-on-question-by-tom-use-2-0-1-and-8-to-make-109).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think...

> $\sqrt{\frac{12!}{8!} + 0!} = \sqrt{11881} = 109$

Answer (score 77):

Probably not the intended answer, but, I propose:

> $108+\sqrt{\sqrt{\ldots \sqrt{2}}}$, with infinitely many square roots.

Explanation:

> Formally:
>  $$\sqrt{\sqrt{\ldots \sqrt{2}}}=\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} s_n=1$$
>  where $s_0=2$ and $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{s_n}$.

Comment: that's an amazing answer --- I never would have thought of that :D

Comment: (+1) very nice. Thanks for following [my proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119894/math-challenges)! :)

Comment: Plus one, but sorry not intended answer

Comment: Technically? What is technically? @Battle Mathematics are not a technique, are a science. And x^(1/n) when n tends to infinite is always 1, since x^0 is 1, for any positive x greater than one.

Comment: @Battle The rules also allow for  $\sqrt{x}$ any number of times, which is what Surb's done here. Also, $1/x^{1/n}$ *does* equal 1 when $n$ tends towards infinity. That's how limits work. Without being able to say "the limit of $x$ as $n$ tends towards infinity equals..." calculus (and many other math disciplines) fall apart. We just wouldn't be able to do any calculations involving infinity.

Comment: +1 for username joke.  (Though slightly misspelled.)

Comment: If you want to be "technically", then the question allows taking the square root any number of times, but it doesn't allow taking an infinitely iterated square root, because an taking an infinitely iterated square root *isn't* taking the square root any number of times. There's no standard definition for *literally* taking a square root infinitely many times; the best you can do is take the limit of a sequence of increasingly many square roots.

Comment: @davidbak I'm not sure which joke you are referring to :). Can you develop?

Comment: @Surb - well, this answer of yours is all about … surds!

Answer (score 28):

This is technically a solution with n-druple factorials. It is not a good solution.

Solution:

> $$\frac{(10!!!)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}{(2+8)!!!}.$$

Explanation:

> First, we note that $2+8=10$. In particular, we can construct the number $10\cdot 7\cdot 4\cdot 1=10!!!=280$ in two different ways.
>  Once we have two copies of $280$, we can construct the number $$280!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!$$ (that's $171$ factorials, so it equals $280\cdot 109$), and then simply divide by $280$ again. This technique can be used to boringly nuke every problem of this form that allows for n-druple factorials: if you want to get some number $K$, you can use the property that $2+8=10$, so you can get two copies of $N$ for some large $N$ (by repeatedly taking factorials from $10$, for example; in terms of big $N$, any $N\geq 2K$ should do it), and then you can take $N!_{N-K}$ ($N-K$ factorials) to get the number $N\cdot K$ - then you just divide by $N$ and now you have $K$.

Comment: Great, general solution! I almost want to mark this as the solution for its ingenuity, but there is a simpler way... You get the plus one of course, and I am so glad that I excluded multiple factorials

Comment: I'm confused, isn't $280!!!!...$ absolutely astronomical compare the the denominator?

Comment: @orlp This is not repeatedly applying the factorial operation, this is the [multiple factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalizations). $n!_{(k)}$ is the product of all the positive integers $m \leq n$ so that $m\equiv n\bmod k$.

Answer (score 22):

If you allow

> decimals

then you can do

> $$109=(.1)^{-2} + 8 + 0!$$

Comment: Sorry no decimals, but plus one

Comment: @tom Oh well. Do you know that a solution exists using only the operations you have allowed?

Comment: Yes there is a solution.... I will start giving hints soon if people don't get it...

Comment: When I plug your solution into my calculator, it gives me 7.1.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief presumably you are calculating (0.1) - 2 + 8 + 0! rather than raising 0.1 to the -2th power.

Answer (score 20):

The trick is to:

> ... count in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal): 21 × 8 + 0! = 109
>
>  (in decimal: 21h = 33 and 109h = 265)

Comment: i like this one.

Comment: great! I like this too, plus one, but sorry there is a decimal solution

Answer (score 14):

Hmmm, possibly:

> Place a vertical mirror by the $2$ to get a $5$. Concatenate the $5$ with the $0$ to get $50$ and take the $38$-factorial (using $38$ exclamations): $50!^{38}=50\cdot12=600$, and then add $1^8=1$: $50!^{38}+1^8=601$. Turn the $601$ upside-down to get $109$.

and for posterity:

> $20!^{15}+1+8$

Comment: +1 that was my first guess also!

Comment: Plus one .... Amazing.  :-).

Comment: I'm missing something here... how does 50!^38 = 50 * 12? Isn't 50!^38 a ridiculously large number?

Comment: it's a multi-factorial, see my answer to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71748/use-2-0-1-and-8-to-make-67

Answer (score 12):

This probably won't count. It uses $!$, but not in $x!$.

> $$108 + !2$$

Explanation

> $!n$ is the number of derangements of n objects. In particular $!2 = 1$.

Comment: Plus one, but sorry not correct

Answer (score 11):

> $$8+2^0=9=09\implies 1\{8+2^0\}=109$$

Comment: Nice try, sorry not correct, but plus one

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Plus one also. It probably can be tagged as lateral thinking (@tom your problem states that you can concatenate _numbers_, not _digits/digit sequences_, so technically it's correct)

Comment: @trolley813 - will edit the question to make this absolutely clear...

Comment: $(+1)$ I like this one :)

Answer (score 10):

I have a few silly answers :) Though, frustratingly, I haven't been able to solve it yet

> $108$++ $= 109$ which you might also write as $108$+<sup>$2$</sup>

or if we are allowing transformation of numbers as I've seen above

> $(2+8)$ concatenated with $0$, with a vertical line (using the $1$) on the RHS to turn it into a $9$

or

> $8-2=6$, which rotated gives $9$, then concatenate $10$ to give $109$

I was thinking about trying to

> Change the base of the numbers

but didn't get anywhere with that idea...

Looking forward to seeing the solution!

Comment: Great answers, I love the 108++. Good job - plus thanks for posting and using the hidden/reveal in your answer. Hope you enjou Puzzling SE (oh and plus one)

Answer (score 9):

I break the rules, BUT!

work with 1 and 20
1 - 20 = -19

> 109 = arccos(sin(-19))

Comment: Ok, you did not use the 8, but that is an interesting and inventive answer - I think it is pretty clever - +1, but not the solution I'm afraid. (I have editted the question to make it clear that you need to use all 4 of the digits)

Comment: How did you find this answer?

Comment: The base of sines and cosines is 90 degrees. You can think of one being plus 90 (sine) and the other being zero (cosine). 109 is 19 different from 90. If you take your difference from 90 (negative number, sine) and then use that as the difference from zero (anticosine), you can solve this. That only applies when your numbers are in the domain of 1 sine and 1 cosine.

Comment: This can be improved a little bit, as $1^8 - 20 = -19$

Answer (score 7):

I have another trigonometric answer.

> $$8^2 - \arctan (0-1) = 109$$
>  the base of tangents is $45$, subtract $-45$, add $45$ to $64$

Comment: neat solution :-) plus one

Answer (score 5):

This won't be correct (concatenation of numbers from calculations is not permitted), but this is a way to cheese it, were that allowed

> Assuming you can have leading 0's... 
>  $ 2^0 = 1$ 
>  $ \sqrt{81} = 09$ 
>  Concatenate the two 
>  $109$

Comment: Nice try, plus one

Answer (score 5):

This is also just for fun, using $!$ in a different way than factorial:

> Uses $!$ as the binary NOT operator (like in C++ and JavaScript)
>  $$108\space+\space!(!2) = 109$$

Explained:

> `!2 == false`, and `!false == true`. `True` is numerically represented as $1$. Then you get $108 + 1$, which equals $109$.

Comment: Nice idea - a bit like the use of the ++ operator in another answer.... :-)

Answer (score 4):

> We include 3 numbers 1,0,8 to 108, 108 can be written as 107+1 
>  now we have 2 remaining from the list of given numbers we can use as 107+(2*1)=109

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I believe this solution is against the rules; you cannot 'decompose' partial results.

Comment: Nice idea, plus one, but not the solution I'm afraid

Answer (score 4):

Easy, just use a one sided self referencing equation, an ingenious mathematical artefact invented by me just now :

> [image]

Comment: ok, plus one for invention

Comment: Yeah I was bored and maths is boring.

Answer (score 2):

Not correct, because it uses the same digits more than once, but you could get there like this:

> $(2 * 8^2) - (8 * 2) - (\frac{1}{2} * 8) + 1^0 = 109$

Comment: $109 = 108+2^0$...

Answer (score 0):

Even if it was solved, I couldn't help myself and came up with a boring

> $$\dfrac{2180}{20}=109$$

Comment: Digits are only allowed to be used once.

Comment: Agh, must have glossed over that one.

Answer (score -4):

My answer is

> $\frac {10!} {8!} + (2 * 8) + 1^0$ = 109

Comment: Christian, interesting answer, but I can see two problems - first it looks to me as if the total is 107 and secondly I am afraid that you use too many digits. The idea is to use 2, 0,  1 and 8 one time only. Thanks for the answer, but I cannot upvote it until it at least  is equal to 109.