# 1984 - take the digits 1,9, 8 and 4 and Hard Challenges!

Tags: mathematics

This is kinda follow up question to:

> Part II... Next year is the 70th anniversary of the publication of the
>   book 1984 by George Orwell. Here is a puzzle to start the anniversary
>   celebrations off a bit early ...
>
> Can you assemble a formula using the numbers $1$, $9$, $8$, and $4$ in
>   any order so that the results equals.... You may use the operations
>   $x + y$, $x - y$, $x \times y$, $x \div y$, $x!$, $\sqrt{x}$,
>   $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}x]{y}$ and $x^y$, as long as all
>   operands are either $1$, $9$, $8$, or $4$. Operands may of course also
>   be derived from calculations e.g. $19*8*(\sqrt{4})$. You may also use
>   brackets to clarify order of operations, and you may concatenate two
>   or more of the four digits you start with (such as $8$ and $4$ to make
>   the number $84$) if you wish. You may only use each of the starting
>   digits once and you must use all four of them. I'm afraid that
>   concatenation of numbers from calculations is not permitted, but
>   answers with concatenations will get plus one from me.
>
> Note that in all the puzzles above  Double, triple, etc. factorials
>   (n-druple-factorials), such as $4!! = 4 \times 2$ are not allowed, but
>   factorials of factorials are fine, such as $(4!)! = 24!$. I will
>   upvote answers with double, triple and n-druple-factorials which get
>   the required answers, but will not mark them as correct - particularly
>   because a general method was developed by [@Carl Schildkraut](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71885/use-2-0-1-and-8-to-make-109/71904#71904) to
>   solve these puzzles.
>
> many thanks to the authors of the similar questions below for
>   inspiring this question.
>
> This is part II after the [first in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72582/1984-take-the-digits-1-9-8-and-4-and-make-246) was solved
>
> - [Use 2 0 1 and 8 to make 67](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71748/use-2-0-1-and-8-to-make-67)
> - [Make numbers 93 using the digits 2, 0, 1, 8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58743/make-numbers-93-using-the-digits-2-0-1-8)
> - [Make numbers 1 - 30 using the digits 2, 0, 1, 8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58633/make-numbers-1-30-using-the-digits-2-0-1-8)

The same rules but there are some different challenges here.

- **Challenge No 1:** Find 142 with the least amount of operations and parenthesis.
- **Challenge No 2:** Find 87 with the least amount of operations and parenthesis.
- **Challenge No 3:** Find 61
- **Challenge No 4:** Find 71 without using power operation (only ^).
- **Challenge No 5:** Find 46

Note that **infinite square root is not allowed** and I will accept the answer which includes all solutions.

Comment: Just double checking square root is counting as a power operation right?

Comment: @gabbo1092 no, I count it as a different operation. adding that info in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Challenge No 1: Find 142 with the least amount of operations and parenthesis.

> $148 - \sqrt{9}! =142$

Challenge No 2: Find 87 with the least amount of operations and parenthesis.

> $91 - 8 + 4 = 87$

Challenge No 3: Find 61

> $1 + \sqrt{9}!\times (8 + \sqrt{4}) =61$

Challenge No 4: Find 71 without using power operation (only ^).

> $81 - \sqrt{9}! -4 = 71$

Challenge No 5: Find 46

> $\sqrt{9}! \times 8 - \sqrt{4} \times 1 = 46$

Comment: fyi: 142 and 87 are not found with the least amount of operations/parenthesis.

Comment: only Challenge No:2 is not okay, but the rest is done.

Comment: Will focus my efforts there

Comment: $\sqrt 9 !$ master race.

Answer (score 3):

Minimum amount of steps for 87 (Challenge No 2) :

> $$\sqrt{841\times9}$$

Comment: yes you got it :)

Comment: I'd argue that that is more than the 91-8+4 answer as they both use two steps (+- and sqrt x respectively) but the second requires an implicit sqrt bracket.

Answer (score 2):

Challenge no. 5 (46):

> $$(8-1)^\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{9}=7^2-3=49-3=46$$

Answer (score 0):

For 142:

> $$\sqrt4(9\times8-1)=142$$

In order:

> $$(-1+9\times8)\sqrt4=142$$

For 87:

> $$8(9+\sqrt4)-1$$

Comment: fyi: 142 and 87 are not found with the least amount of operations/parenthesis.